# Intellij: Running jar from maven dependancy

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, handlebars.java

I am new to maven, I have some .hbs (handle-bar template files), I have "handlebars-proto", which includes premade handlebar server.

https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java (search for handlebars-proto)

I've added the dependency to my pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
  <artifactId>handlebars-proto</artifactId>
  <version>${current-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Documentation states, I should be able to run it using,

```
java -jar handlebars-proto-${current-version}.jar -dir myTemplates
```

How can I create a Intellij Run Configuration to do same as above. I tried creating JAR task runner & using "handlevar-proto-{version}.jar" but it's unable to find the jar file. In general how to run a jar from the maven in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

There is option in run configurations to configure JAR Application

[image]